# Is it possible to change a Visual Studio projects Windows SDK version from the command line?

Tags: sdk, command, version, line, upgrade

Once my Visual Studio project is generated it needs to upgrade the platform tool set and Windows SDK versions to the latest versions.  I'm trying to find a way to upgrade the projects Windows SDK version from the command line, rather than in the GUI.

I currently using the following command:

`devenv Myproject.sln /upgrade`

The problem is that this command only upgrades the platform tool set and not the Windows SDK version.

Is there a way to upgrade/change the Visual Studio projects Windows SDK version from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on Microsoft Q&A answered this question with the following solution which works:

In powershell:

```
$content=Get-Content -Path 'C:\Myproject.vcxproj'
 $newContent=$content -replace '10.0.19041.0', '10.0.22000.0'
 $newContent|Set-Content -Path 'C:\Myproject.vcxproj'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).